# Why does this test fail when run with dotCover?

Tags: c#, rider, dotcover

With Rider 2018.2 we've got dotCover support for our unit test cases, which is great, and I moved to take advantage of it immediately. I have however run into an odd issue with unit tests failing only when run for coverage, and only when xUnit's ITestOutputHelper is used to write information. The error isn't especially clear on why, but maybe there's some interaction going on between libraries while run in this particular way that's unclear to me.

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading;
using Moq;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

public class CoverFail
{
    public ITestOutputHelper OutputHelper { get; }
    public CoverFail(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
    {
        OutputHelper = outputHelper;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var mockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
        var mockIdentity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
        mockPrincipal.SetupGet(m => m.Identity).Returns(mockIdentity.Object);

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = mockPrincipal.Object;

        OutputHelper.WriteLine("Goodbye");
    }
}
```

The exception generated is:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>   Type 'Moq.CastleProxyFactory+IncludeObjectMethodsHook' in Assembly 'Moq, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920' is not marked as serializable.

My packages.config is:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.9.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="xunit" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

The project is targeting .NET 4.7.1 and using the C# 7.0 language level.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well ... dotCover in Visual Studio.

Comment: You should file an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/rider